# How to inject second element ids to the website elements

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, I'm looking to tag all the elements in a web page (or at least links and buttons) by adding an id attribute for example custom-id = "12345".

My concern here is how to maintain those IDs unique and static for each element, especially when in the future (developers or business change some elements)a page can have more or less elements, and just  iterating through the document elements to assign ids could change the order of the elements and the ids, what is not preferable to have static IDS.

What i'm looking to do again, is to have the same ID for the same element, even if the page hierarchy changes many times..

Tagged Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 custom-id = "1">My First Heading</h1>

<p custom-id = "2">My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When elements changes it goes wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p custom-id = "1">My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The correct should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p custom-id = "2">My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The script looks like this:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    all[i].setAttribute("data-custom-id", i);
}
```

Thanks All!
Hedi

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: What is the purpose of this? There may be a much better way to do it.

Comment: `custom-id` is not correct attribute. Use `data-custom-id="1234"`

Comment: What i'm looking to do again, is to have the same ID for the same element, even if the page hierarchy changes many times..

Comment: I've not wrote the script yet, because i know it will work as i described and not as i want. I've just added a sample code to the post.

Comment: if u want an element to get an ID and KEEP it (forever?) you cant get around using a database (MySQL for example)

Comment: @zeropublix You are right. i think there is no way to bypass a DB.. it's sad.

Comment: well u can also use a json or something. or XML . but something persitent needs to be there for sure

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something similar to the .is() selector (jQuery)

```
$('#theid').is($('p')); ==> true
```

This way, you can use this in your conditional to add the appropriate data-id to the right element tag, as you were implying above.

Non jQuery solution (from http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```
var matches = function(el, selector) {
  return (el.matches || el.matchesSelector || el.msMatchesSelector || el.mozMatchesSelector || el.webkitMatchesSelector || el.oMatchesSelector).call(el, selector);
};

matches(el, '.my-class');
```

or..

```
el === otherEl
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

i think i found it:

Now, i think about another way. Generating a unique key to identify the element from the element itself, and make this available to the TMS, and i think this one should work..

Example:

The plugin should run always before the Analytics rules.

Step1: Loop and Read The elements:

```
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
```

Step2: Convert to String:

```
"<h1>My First Heading</h1>"
```

Step3: Convert the string to Key!! (using cryptoJS for example):

```
"dhked543e5de"
```

Then add this to the element:

```
<h1 custom-elm-key = "dhked543e5de">My First Heading</h1>
```